# printing the contents of function template taking class pointer

Tags: c++, templates

I have difficulty in printing the string value present in a class used inside a function template.
Following is the code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
using namespace std;
template <typename T>

    class Test1{
        public:
            int val1 = 10;
            string val2 = "hello"; 
    };

    class Test2{
        public:
            int val1 = 20;
            string val2 = "hai";
    };
    class Queue{
    public:
        void append(T & item)
        {
            {
                std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutex);
                cout<<"string to be added "<<item->val2;
                mQueue.push_back(item);
            }
        }
    private:
        std::vector<T> mQueue;
    };
    int main(int argc, char** argv) {
        Test2 *new_val;
        Queue *data;
        data->append(new_val);
        return 0;
    }
```

Can anyone pl point out the error and what can be done to print the strings of various classes inside the function template.

Comment: The code you show won't even build. Is that what you're asking about? Please read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: `data->append(new_val);` dereferences an uninitialized pointer and passes another uninitialized pointer. Why are you trying to use pointers at all?

Answer (score 1):

Attention: when you write

```
template <typename T>

    class Test1{
        public:
            int val1 = 10;
            string val2 = "hello"; 
    };

    class Test2{
        public:
            int val1 = 20;
            string val2 = "hai";
    };
    // ...
```

you define `Test1` as a template class, `Test2` and the following classes as ordinary (not template) classes.

So, when you write

```
class Queue{
public:
    void append(T & item)
    {
        {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutex);
            cout<<"string to be added "<<item->val2;
            mQueue.push_back(item);
        }
    }
private:
    std::vector<T> mQueue;
};
```

the compiler doesn't know what is `T` because `T` is the template parameter of `Test1`.

I suppose you want a template `Queue`

```
template <typename T>
class Queue{
   // ...
};

// ...

Test2 new_val;

Queue<Test2> data;

data.append(new_val);
```

Observe that I've also trasformed the pointers in object.
Suggestion: avoid pointer until it's clear to you as use they.